# Using sub to reduce length of text

Tags: r, gsub

How can I use sub to reduce something like this:

Bacteria; Actinobacteria; Actinobacteria; Micrococcales; Brevibacteriaceae; Brevibacterium

To this:

Brevibacterium

Basically I just want to remove the first 5 words so I'm left with the genus only

Comment: `strsplit` is another option, provided all strings are consistent with your example. For example: `strsplit("Bacteria; Actinobacteria; Actinobacteria; Micrococcales; Brevibacteriaceae; Brevibacterium", "; ")[[1]][6]`

Comment: Do you want to remove first 5 words or keep the last word in the string? Or any of it would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub(".*;\\s*", "", String)
```

Explanation:
.*   - matches any number of characters at the beginning
;    - matches the last ;
\s* - matches zero or more white-space characters after the ;

So the first expression matches everything up to the first non-blank character after the last ;.  It is replaced with the empty string, so it just deletes everything at the beginning.

Comment: That did it, can you explain what all the characters mean?

Comment: Thank you, on top of that, I have a data frame with 440 rows of lines similar to that. How can I change all 440 rows of that dataframe to show the Genus only? Keeping in mind several of the rows just say "Remainder" rather than a taxonomic string

Comment: Just apply the above expression to the entire column.

Comment: how would I write that? For example if it is called df, would I write:
df <- sub(".*;\\s*", "", df$Taxon)

Comment: `df$Taxon <- sub(".*;\\s*", "", df$Taxon)`

Comment: ahh that works thankyou. If I wanted to leave one leavel up, so remove the first 4 words how would I alter the script? I just noticed several lines where the Genus is given is NA so I need to go up a level

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, unfortunately using that code gave me the same output as the original one. Back to the original question I need to change the text to Brevibacteriaceae; Brevibacterium now rather than just Brevibacterium

Comment: Sorry,  my error. Should have been` df$Taxon <- sub(".*;\\s*(.*;)", "\\1", df$Taxon)`